# Meta analysis: How to assess the quality of each of the individual studies in a systematic way?

Tags: meta-analysis, quality-control

I have a meta analysis at hand. I have reported on the quality of the included studies in a narrative form. But after I was requested about "quality assessment". I guess it might be something else, a statistical model for example, something like weighting.

I googled it but to my surprise, no good links were found in the first half an hour of searching. So I am asking here.

Plus from the vague comments of the reviewers, it appeared to me that there is a "quality assessment" of the meta-analysis itself too. I mean something analytical and other than PRISMA.

Do you have any advice or link regarding which tests or analyses should I do for this quality assessment purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that it could mean including some study-level quality indicators as moderator variables. If those variables are found to have an effect in the “wrong” direction (e.g. if effect sizes tend to be smaller for studies with larger sample sizes) and the effect is smaller or even negligible for the high-quality studies (e.g. controlled experiments as opposed to observational studies), the robustness of the findings would be called into question. You can also ask experts to rate each study's quality on one or more scales and include that as a moderator variable. Does all this make sense in your case?

Potential quality indicators:

- Randomized trial vs. observational study/self-selection
- Prospective vs. retrospective
- Type of control group
- Blindness (of the patient or physician to the treatment arm)
- Outcome (subjective improvement/self-report vs. “hard” outcomes like death)
- Sample size
- Source of funding
- Length of time between treatment and last follow-up
- Quality of the reporting (whether or not reports on each primary study include sufficient details on the population, diagnosis, etc.)

The key being to include these indicators in the meta-analysis and to quantify their impact, as opposed to merely using them as inclusion criteria or discussing them narratively.

Comment: So many thanks dear Gael for the very informative response. Yes that makes sense. Then I am to calculate the study weights and precisions, I guess. These points you mentioned are very good. I would add them all to my study!

Comment: There remains only one aspect: Is there a statistical method for combining those ratings into some standardized measures? Something like weighting again, but more comprehensive. I found this PDF but it was only a presentation, so although gave me some clues, it was not complete. http://www.campbellcollaboration.org/artman2/uploads/1/Williams_quality_assessment.pdf

Comment: I think this is like the "moderator variable" you already mentioned.

Comment: Did you mean "CONSORT"?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your last questions. I don't know about these composite “quality scales” but it sounds like an interesting approach. I am more familiar with meta-analysis testing each quality indicator separately. How many you can reasonably include in the model also depends on the number of studies of each kind.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. I will go with what you said (single variables) and would add a handful of them. The number of studies is good (+100) so it doesn't bother if I add about 10 IVs, I think (the rule of thumb of ten data pieces per IV).

Comment: Make sure this approach is valid - I vaguely remember a caution against using study quality as a variable in meta-regression. Odds are if there's a paper on it, it's written by Sander Greenland or Charles Poole.

Comment: @EpiGrad I don't know about that but there is a long standing debate between the “include only the best studies and estimate the effect size” and “include everything and test” approaches. I would say it's more a difference in philosophy than a question of one approach being unambiguously valid or invalid.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. EpiGrad I know that based on SE, they measure study weights and use it in meta-regression. So at some point, it sounds possible to include the quality as an important variable (I mean weight). However, I am not sure about other forms of quality assessment. OK I will first go with a table of qualitative information on different aspects of quality. If I was asked, I would convert them to ranks and new variables. Also as I cited above, here is a brief overview on such quantitative methods

Comment: http://www.campbellcollaboration.org/artman2/uploads/1/Williams_quality_assessment.pdf

Comment: Could you be more specific on what study designs you are including in your meta-analysis, and what tool/ checklist you used to gauge study quality.

Answer (score 0):

To assess the quality of studies, one should know the reliability of data used for the generation of the effect-size. If the reliability index is low, the result of study should be suspected. Check for the reliability indexes or validity coefficients generally incorporated in the published or unpublished studies.